# Delayed ajax response vs sockets? node.js

Tags: ajax, sockets

I need in my multiplayer game the server to send some data to a client when another player enters the game. For this I've been thinking that I need :

1. A socket
2. Ajax requests every X seconds

But now I'm thinking about delayed ajax. Imagine the client asks the server "the player entered in the game?" and the server doesnt reply right now, but it will wait for that player to enter and then it will respond to the first client "yes, player 2 entered the game".

Now what about resources on the server, which approach is lighter in server resources?

1. Sockets
2. Delayed ajax

I think that a delayed ajax is keeping a connection open, so it's not so great too, but tell me about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a Comet technology which is an implementation of
   long-polling you need for "delayed AJAX".
2. Another option is    WebSockets, but it is quite a new feature not
   supported in many    browsers.
3. Plain sockets are the easiest way to go as long as they do not
   require a lot of traffic (which comes with constant ajax-polling),
   and can handle "real full-duplex". The best choice if latency is the priority.
4. If the game is large, the best way to go is for non-blocking IO + Reactor pattern,
   which will allow you to server millions of requests concurrently on
   the server. And in a socket-like fashion. Unlike 3, much less memory consumption.

Comment: The game is turn based and very simple. Is based on canvas, html5, so requires a decent browser (then websockets might be fine, right?). The server I would need it to run is a free tier of Amazon EC2. How many websockets do you think it can handle?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the memory and processor (and number of ports =)). Sry, cant calculate the exact number on your Amazon plan - but you can calculate it by finding out how much space is taken by 1 thread and its local objects and multiplying by the expected number of clients. + websockets can also be implemented in non-blocking manner (after all websockets are the same "simple sockets", initiated by the browser). In case they are non-blocking, their number might grow exponentially.

Comment: From what I know node.js only has one thread... and are non-blocking

Comment: Then, its a way to go. I personally program in java most of the time, so I cant consult you on Node.js much.

Comment: I've already switched to sockets.io, until now works fine, but no load eighter. I like the thing that I can switch to ajax just by a flag, so there is no problem at all if things go wrong (: thanks to abstraction